# Is using cat to read data from standard input and write it to a file not a useless use of cat?

Tags: shell, posix, cat

I want to write a shell script that accepts data from standard input, write it to a file and then does something with it.

For the purpose of this question, let us assume, that my script should accept standard input, write it to `in.txt`, then grep a string `"foo"` from it and write the output to `out.txt`.

I wrote this script.

```
cat > in.txt
grep foo in.txt > out.txt
```

As explained in some of the answers below, one could just use

```
tee in.txt | grep foo > out.txt
```

What if it is some other command instead of `grep` that does not read from standard input? Does it become a valid use of cat then?

Here is one such example with `chmod`.

```
cat > in.txt
chmod -v 600 in.txt > out.txt
```

It is a requirement that both the input and the output must be available in files after the script ends.

I would like to know if my code is making a useless use of `cat` or if this is a perfectly valid scenario when `cat` may be invoked like this?

Also, is there a way to rewrite this code without using `cat` such that it does not make a useless use of any command?

Note: I am concerned with answers that applies to any POSIX compliant shell, not just Bash or Linux.

Comment: In your example, why not `grep foo <in.txt >out.txt && nextcmd out.txt`? (making use of a *compound command*) (**note:** the initial redirection is optional)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I fail to see how your comment is relevant. I am already doing `grep foo in.txt > out.txt` where `in.txt` contains the text that was read from standard input. What's `nextcmd out.txt` for?

Comment: Very few commands won't read from stdin. Occassionally you need to specify `-` to indicate that the input is in stdin. Very very occassionally you need to spell it out: `/dev/stdin`

Comment: @rici Commands like `chmod`, `chown`, etc. cannot work on standard input. Changing the ownership or permission of a file after creating it is a valid scenario to consider. Also, `/dev/stdin` is not defined in POSIX.

Comment: @LoneLearner your statement was *"accepts data from standard input, write it to a file and then does something with it.*", and then your concern switches to UUOC. The `nextcmd` was to address "*do something with it*". Aside from `cat` being appropriate for 2+ files, I'm a bit confused as to your desired goal -- other than simply fleshing out the issues.

Comment: If you need to create a file, by all means use cat. That's what it is there for. Using it instead of telling some other utility what file to wirk on is uuoc. And tee won't help you with chmod :-)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I still don't understand how your first comment is related to this discussion. How do you accept data from standard input and write it to a file without using `cat`? The `grep in.txt` command is "doing something with it". You could as well use `chmod` instead of `grep`and in this case `chmod 600 in.txt` would be "doing something with it".

Comment: "How do you accept data from standard input and write it to a file without using cat?". Normally, by redirecting the data stream to the file instead of the stdin for the shell process.  :)

Answer (score 5):

Its a valid use of `cat` but the `tee` command is what you want. Its designed to write everything to a file and to stdout.

```
tee in.txt | grep foo > out.txt
```

Comment: However, in the general case where `some_command` may not read text from standard input, I would still have to go for `cat > in.txt; some_command in.txt > out.txt`, right? Or should I rather go for `tee in.txt > /dev/null; some_command in.txt > out.txt`?

Comment: `tee in.txt > /dev/null` is much worse than `cat > in.txt`.

Comment: @LoneLearner - right. `tee` is good if the program reads `stdin`. If it wants a file, `cat > in.txt` is the way to go. As long as the file isn't gigantic, it will be in the operating system's disk cache so it will be fast.

Answer (score -1):

> The purpose of cat is to concatenate (or "catenate") files. If it's only one file, concatenating it with nothing at all is a waste of time, and costs you a process. [-- era eriksson](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

So, yes, it's de facto useless. The `tee` solution strikes me as the most POSIXy way to do this, but you could deploy shell-specific constructs if the cost of two processes was too high.

Comment: What if it is some other command instead of `grep` that does not read from standard input? Does it become a valid use of cat then? I have added this now to my question.